Flask/SQLAlchemy How can I correct <built-in function> field when creating table with reflect?
I want to use metadata.reflect() and generate the existing tables. Tried Method 1 and Method 2 in code block to generate the table. They both give the same error about the Mapper not being able to assemble any primary key columns for mapped table. I think it's because of the <built-in function id> field. How can I solve mapping issue?
Solved: Error started at the data upload (outside of SQL and SQLAlchemy) using Pandas to generate the index.
        content = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        content.to_sql(table_name,
                       con=engine,
                       if_exists='replace')
        ## removed index=True and index_label=id from the args

What I've done:

Read the package docs' tutorial: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/models/
I've checked the few other similar questions to this:


getting sqlalchemy view reflection to work in flask-sqlalchemy
how to reflect an existing table by using flask_sqlalchemy


Asked ChatGPT

One suggested solution for the <built-in function id> is to declare a primary key, but I thought my original CREATE TABLE statement does that. Does it not? I've tried using __mapper_args__ on my own, but can't figure out how to assign the shelf_id or id (I've tried both). The ultimate workaround seems to be to write out every table column, but the database isn't finalized yet, so...
engine = create_engine(AppConfig.DBURI, echo=False)
meta = MetaData()
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))
def init_db(engine):
    meta.init_db()
    meta.create_all(bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.reflect(bind=engine)

# Method 1
class Bookshelf(Base):
    __table__ = Table("bookshelf",
                      Base.metadata,
                      Column('shelf_id', Integer),
                      autoload_with=engine,
                      extend_existing=True)

# Method 2
# class Bookshelf(Base):
#    __table__ = Base.metadata.tables['bookshelf']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for table in Base.metadata.tables.values():
        logging.debug(f"{table.name}")
        for column in table.c:
            logging.debug(f"{column.name}")

Errors:
raise sa_exc.ArgumentError(
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper[Bookshelf(bookshelf)] could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'bookshelf'

If I run the same code above without the Table class, I get:
2024-05-31 11:42:23,355 [DEBUG] bookshelf.<module>, line 67: bookshelf
2024-05-31 11:42:23,356 [DEBUG] bookshelf.<module>, line 69: <built-in function id>
2024-05-31 11:42:23,357 [DEBUG] bookshelf.<module>, line 69: shelf_label
2024-05-31 11:42:23,357 [DEBUG] bookshelf.<module>, line 69: directory_name
2024-05-31 11:42:23,358 [DEBUG] bookshelf.<module>, line 69: url

The table was created separately by database_admin.py.
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bookshelf(
                shelf_id INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                shelf_label TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL ,
                directory_name TEXT NOT NULL,
                url TEXT NOT NULL,
                creation_date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                updated_date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                PRIMARY KEY (shelf_id),
                UNIQUE(shelf_label, directory_name)
            );

Also tried it with shelf_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL JIC.

I figured it out. The problem was prior to SQLAlchemy. I was importing my csv file using Pandas to_sql() with args index=True, index_label=id. I took those out, recreated the database and voila!
